# Function return type based on optional params

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access an array of data stored in React Context using a custom hook.

- If I pass in no parameters, I want the whole array of data
- If I pass in an ID, I want the hook to return that one item

```
type Data = { id: string };

const useMyData = (id?: string) => {
  const data: Data[] = useContext(MyDataProvider);
  if (id) return data.find(item => item.id === id); // type: Data
  return data; // type: Data[]
}
```

### What I've Tried

I've tried function overloading, but I get `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`

```
function useMyData(): Data[]
function useMyData(id?: string): Data { /* ... */ }
```

I've tried Generics to no avail: `Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'T extends undefined ? Data[] : Data`

```
const useMyData = <T extends string | undefined>(
  id?: T,
): T extends undefined ? Data[] : Data => { /* ... */ };
```

I've tried Typing the hook, but I get every combination of "Is not assignable to" error you could imagine. `Data | Data[] is not assignable to Data[]`, `unknown is not assignable to Data`, etc.

```
type TUseMyData = (() => Data[]) | ((id: string) => Data);

const useMyData: TUseMyData = (id?: string) => { /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use this implementation to start with:

```
const theData: Data[] = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }];
const useMyDataUnion = (id?: string) => {
    if (typeof id === "string")
        return theData.find(item => item.id === id); // type: Data | undefined
    return theData; // type: Data[]
}
```

Note that the return type is either `Data[]` or `Data | undefined`, since `Array.prototype.find()` is not guaranteed to find anything.  That function has the type signature

```
// const useMyDataUnion: (id?: string | undefined) => Data | Data[] | undefined
```

which is true but not specific enough for your needs.

---

First we'll do it with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function useMyDataOverload(): Data[]; // call signature 1
function useMyDataOverload(id: string): Data | undefined; // call signature 2
// implementation:
function useMyDataOverload(id?: string) {
    return useMyDataUnion(id);
}
```

Note that overloads separate the *call signatures* from the *implementation* of a function, and the implementation of a function is *not* added to the list of call signatures.  In your example you were treating the implementation as if it were another call signature, and the compiler was unhappy.

For `useMyDataOverload()`, there are two ways to call it.  You can either call it with no parameters and get a `Data[]` out, or call it with a `string` parameter and get a `Data | undefined` out.  The implementation has to accept both possible ways of calling it... a single optional `string` parameter meets that criterion.  It also has to return a type that is compatible with the *union* of return types of the call signatures.  It also meets that criterion.  Note that the return type rule is *necessary* but not *sufficient* for type safety.  You could just as easily change the implementation to something like:

```
function useMyDataBadOverload(): Data[];
function useMyDataBadOverload(id: string): Data | undefined;
function useMyDataBadOverload(id?: string) {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? theData.find(i => Math.random() < 0.5) : theData;
}
```

which certainly returns a `Data[] | Data | undefined` but is not guaranteed to return the right type.  So be careful with implementing an overloaded function.

Let's see if it works:

```
console.log(useMyDataOverload().map(x => x.id)); // ["a", "b", "c"] 
console.log(useMyDataOverload("a")?.id); // "a"
console.log(useMyDataOverload("z")?.id); // undefined
```

That all looks right, and the compiler accepts it.  I think overloads are probably the right solution here.  One drawback is that you can only call one call signature at a time; if the compiler can't tell which one you're calling, there will be an error:

```
const params = Math.random() < 0.5 ? [] as const : ["a"] as const;
useMyDataOverload(...params); // error, no acceptable overload
```

---

You could also try to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).  My implementation would look like this:

```
const useMyDataConditional = <T extends [id: string] | []>(
    ...params: T
) => useMyDataUnion(params[0]) as T extends [] ? Data[] : (Data | undefined);
// need type assertion
```

This is using `T` as the type of the parameter list, and is either a single `string` parameter or an empty parameter list.  The return type is conditional similar to what you were doing.

But as you noticed, the compiler is unable to *verify* that the return *value* is assignable to the generic conditional return *type*.  This is true of overloads, also, but with overloads the compiler is intentionally "lax" about type checking and lets things through it can't be sure about.  Here, it is "strict" and lets just about nothing through.  If I just *annotate* the function, I'll get an error:

```
const useMyDataBadConditional = <T extends [id: string] | []>(
    ...params: T): T extends [] ? Data[] : (Data | undefined) =>
    useMyDataUnion(params[0]); // error
```

There is an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), asking for some way the compiler can inspect a function implementation to verify that it is assignable to a generic conditional type.  For now though, the solution I'd recommend is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  Don't *ask* the compiler if the return type is `T extends [] ? Data[] : (Data | undefined)`; instead, you *tell* it so with `as`.

Let's make sure it works:

```
console.log(useMyDataConditional().map(x => x.id)); // ["a", "b", "c"] 
console.log(useMyDataConditional("a")?.id); // "a"
console.log(useMyDataConditional("z")?.id); // undefined
useMyDataConditional(...params); // Data | Data[] | undefined
```

All of that works as expected, and even the `...params` version is supported.  Personally I'd lean toward overloads here, as the conditional type is more complex and doesn't give a huge benefit.  But either way works.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeUCWATAXFAZ2ACdMA7AcygF8BuAKHoGMB7MoqYACwnkXz5wA2gF0UUIRhz4ARHBk0ANOix4oMgEYLqyqWplNtIhq3bAoAVwIQAsiEEBVMpjbiAFDgD8+IqUoBKFAA+dHoocKwAMyg3UEgWaJwUZFQZX3IKGX8wiNziCGALYjJOHkEAOkjybA9gCABbYKw6+vKklNQcf1ooAHpeznAIAQQkAB9LMmwIKrIIbBzw-MLi0t5Rnv7ByBHEUXpqei3TDitbe1GnFzJ8D2xvQhIMqAmLKZnyecDkEMEX2FGon+b2ms3mjEibyYwGulmsdkEAHkAG4QYgAGxYcBq-l2wmMfQGTDg6PRhEwFDICCK0AAjPRIWRobCzgjRii0ZjsXcfE8Anjge8wdhNkSSWSCBSqStoAAmI4DTD1MDohoQMiIGGuDQQTEAdwZUK1JVZF0QHIxWJqXl5fgogTQiygyyKJvhZrgVzYd26BwhRpZ7sEACFsRauTi8aIGIzma5TSGw6jLdzpI87biAYhBaDPiLDUzjXDzonsOGrXcHukAqE8gVXVAbAguOViHApix6m5AgAeKAABnKAFYoJ41hVZtamk3uK329hO92oH3B0PAvhuOtEAxDowTixVeVMRQ3An2cmI93yvU4GA3AAPJr3trYfzdQkSOQyZSab-qQxiMwbAEAeEBHiwJ5nuaF4Vl+-ieC+75bF+QHsKB4GQUG56crBABeWQIV0oqTLmcwLKhHBgHAbb1AQ4gzi2bYdl2vYDsOo4SGIcB0Sc5j4EIX5cTxwHAAw9BQXA5bcuUMlUTRBBIQMaLECwxDKGQLBQHATBMBAYCIBoqpQCwMHYnuInFmyiAAMJsNgmDGiS4g9gAKlAED3nUUx0UIabVhQYgTKIQRuE6MnlHJcC0fgLn0N8IQSV6ZBuJFtFCP2IiBNxUBuR5XnYD5YhjoIQK3H8rxCnmvpbHM8zbNA3HWMQxrmWYlkeqG2C2VMDnXE5qCue5nnqgVEh+XyAX-MFoW5OFqUEDFma5cN3mcRxJViGVow5h8ZHxU6iXON683pZlxHKapjAUehx6nlhNl2b1bAkleN53o+PxQM+XSKZ+8g-loP4AVA12HrdEndfZjnom4cGEa+xEofuYMQXdJajJDT1UjDMj4fBiHESCu3ghDj3Q24c3UVFCnEeVWb4jtwpXfQQA)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. While I'd prefer to use Arrow Functions here, I'm more than happy to settle for regular functions + Overloads to accomplish this.

> In your example you were treating the implementation as if it were another call signature, and the compiler was unhappy.

That was definitely the missing ingredient, and everything works perfectly now. Thanks!